# Formula for calculating Euclidian direction in Excel

Tags: excel, euclidean-distance

I am calculating Euclidian distance between points in an Excel application, and also need to be able to specify the direction of the difference in two-dimensional location for each pair of points.

Does anyone know how to implement this in Excel?

Below is a simplified illustration of my current Euclidian distance calculation. I have two points, and calculate how far apart Point1 is from Point2. But I would also like to find the direction (in degrees preferably) between Point1 and Point2.

[image: illustration of simplified Euclidian distance calculation]

Comment: By "direction" do you want the degrees of rotation necessary to reach B from A?  That is just a little trig involving the inverse tangent function.

Comment: This is just math. Your key here is the formula to determine the length of a hypotenuse for a right triangle: a^2 + b^2 = c^2. First, create your imaginary triangle - in the case above, that's Point 1, going to the right 4 spaces of .5 each, and down 2 spaces of .5 each, ending at Point 2. So, 2^2 + 1^2 = 4 + 1 = 5 = C^2. Squareroot of both sides gives us C = 2.236. Now figure out how to plug the Excel values you already have into that formula.

Comment: Thanks both! Useful in pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For direction, you could use the angle that the vector from point one to point two makes with respect to the positive x axis:

```
=DEGREES(ATAN2(B3-B2,C3-C2))
```

this will return a number between -180 and +180 degrees. The `ATAN2` function is given by `ATAN2(x,y) = arctan(y/x)` with the refinement that it returns pi/2 rather than a division by 0 error if x = 0 and also gives an answer in the appropriate quadrant.

Comment: Excellent - just what I was after. Thanks very much (too long since my trigonometry classes to great opportunity to revisit this).